# Complex Analysis, Contour Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have difficulties with the following question:
Let a be a given complex number satisfying $0 < \left\vert a\right\vert < 2$ and let $\gamma$ be the unit circle of radius $3$ oriented in the positive sense.
$$
\mbox{Determine the value of the contour integral}\quad
\oint_{\gamma}{\Re\left(z\right) \over z - a}\,\mathrm{d}z\quad
\mbox{in terms of}\ a.
$$

I have tried expressed $\Re\left(z\right)$ as $\left(z + \bar{z}\right)/2$, and I am stuck at this question. Someone please help give some inspiration, thank you so much !.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: When $|z|=3$ then $2{\rm Re\ } z = z+\bar{z} = z + \frac{9}{z}$ and you are then reduced to a calculation of
$$ \frac12 \oint_{\partial B_3} (z+\frac{9}{z}) \frac{1}{z-a} dz=\oint \frac{z/2}{z-a} + \frac{9}{2a} \left( \frac{1}{z-a} - \frac{1}{z}\right) dz.$$
If you know C.I.F then this should be feasible.

Comment: Hi Mr Rugh :) I meant to say that it is the counterclockwise sense. And I haven't learnt about the Cauchy Residue Formula, is there any other way to do it then?

Comment: Since z + 9/z is not analytic within B3, as it contains the origin.

Comment: @user376473 Then I'm afraid you're going to have to parametrize...and it is not going to be very pretty.

Comment: Do you mean I have to express z as 3eitetha

Comment: In that case, how would I be able to apply the Cauchy Integral Formula?

Comment: Yes, you have got it (just put in a factor $i$ as well)!

Answer (score 0):

On the "unit circle of radius 3 oriented in the positive sense" we can write $3cos(\theta)+ 3i sin(\theta)$ with $\theta$ going from 0 to $2\pi$.  The real part of z is $3cos(\theta)$ so this integral is $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{cos(\theta)}{cos(\theta)+ isin(\theta)- a} d\theta$

Comment: That works, but that is very hard to integrate, I can't seem to find the antiderivative of that function.